# My JS Array print is only showing end vaules

Tags: javascript, html

so abit of back story - I am creating a personal note keep 'thing' and I have ran into this problem:

when using:

```
for (i = 0; i < note_title.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("current_titles").innerHTML = (note_title[i] + "<br />");
};
for (i = 0; i < note_content.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("current_contents").innerHTML = (note_content[i] + "<br />");
};
```

the code will only print out the last values, rather than the whole list. Why might this be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always reset the `innerHTML` property thus overwriting the old values.

The solution is to store the generated HTML in a variable (a string) and set that as the `innerHTML` value after the loop.

**Do not** use `innerHTML += ""`. This dramatically affects your site's preformance.

```
var currentTitlesStr = "";

for (i = 0; i < note_title.length; i++) {
    currentTitlesStr += note_title[i] + "<br />";
}
document.getElementById("current_titles").innerHTML = currentTitlesStr;


var noteContentsStr = "";

for (i = 0; i < note_content.length; i++) {
    noteContentsStr += note_content[i] + "<br />";
}
document.getElementById("current_contents").innerHTML = nodeContentsStr;
```

Comment: You missed += on current_titles, but good job - thanks for the quick response :D

Comment: @user2995986 Good catch, thanks for the correction. By the way, welcome to StackOverflow! Please [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/191400) if it solves your problem.

Comment: I found another error :P If i were to refresh the page, which this code within it - it would overlap for example: the first time it would print "A, B" but the next time I refresh it would add to it "A A, B B" - thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: @user2995986 Well, I cannot see any direct relationship between my code and your issue. The code always clears the HTML before filling it with the concatenated values of the arrays `note_title` or `note_content`. Please show more code.

Comment: @user2995986 It's really hard to find the bug you're facing when only seeing a screenshot. A wild guess: reset `note_title_str` and `note_content_str` in the setTimeout() block: `note_title_str = ""; note_content_str = "";`

Comment: Figured it out, was using the variables globally rather than in the function. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Add += instead of =**

```
for (i = 0; i < note_title.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("current_titles").innerHTML += (note_title[i] + "<br />");
};
for (i = 0; i < note_content.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("current_contents").innerHTML += (note_content[i] + "<br />");
};
```

Comment: As I said this solution is not recommended due to performance reasons. You rewrite the whole HTML in each iteration!